# How to insert a character with its encoded value in a PostgreSQL non-unicode database?

Tags: database, postgresql, character-encoding

I create a database and a table in PostgreSQL with the statements below:

```
CREATE DATABASE pg_euc_cn WITH ENCODING = 'EUC_CN' LC_COLLATE = 'C' LC_CTYPE = 'C' TEMPLATE=template0;

CREATE TABLE t1 (VALUE VARCHAR(3));
```

I want to insert the character '单' into this table, with its euc-cn encoded value 'B5A5' or its unicode code point '5355' instead of the character itself.

I tried with

```
insert into t1 values (x'B5A5')
```

and

```
insert into t1 values (0xB5BA)
```

but they do not work for PostgreSQL.
What it the correct statement to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) covers that:

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter `E` (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., `E'foo'`. [...]
>
> `\uxxxx`, `\Uxxxxxxxx` (x = 0–9, A–F) — 16 or 32-bit hexadecimal Unicode character value

So `E'\u5355'` for '单'.

There is also [another way to write Unicode-escaped strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE).